# How do I defeat skeletron again?

Tags: terraria-console

I have defeated skeletron quite a long time ago, and I want to try to get some of his rarer items(Like the book of skulls, and the trophy) without making another world. How do I summon him again? I'm on console version (Xbox).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Killing Skeletron for the first time allowed the Clothier to move in to your house.

In order to summon Skeletron you will need to kill the Clothier at night with the Clothier Voodoo doll equipped.

The Clotheir Voodoo doll has a 0.33% chance to drop from Angry Bones and Dark Casters in the Dungeon.